# Грамотное оформление документации в Python

Tags: python, оформление

Правильно оформлена документация данного примера класса?

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, label="", icon=None, menu=None, quit=True):
        """
        :param label: подпись трея

        :type icon: str
        :param icon: путь к иконке

        :type menu: list
        :param menu: [("Подпись кнопки", пользовательская функция))]

        :param quit: если True - будет создан пункт "Quit" с функцией выхода

        """
```

Если нет, подскажите, как это сделать грамотно, чтобы не было стыдно за свой код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз уж Вы задались подобным вопросом, советую вам почитать **перевод** статей про оформление кода на языке Python [отсюда.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vhrh6d2j57ul80j/GooglePythonStyleGuide(RUS).zip)

Хоть определенного (единого) стандарта на этот счет и нет, однако, окружать аргумент с 2-х сторон `:` - это, по-моему, лишнее. Достаточно ставить один знак `:`, например, так:

```
param label: Подпись трея
```

Подробенее см. ссылку.

Comment: Кстати, а Вы используйте автоматическую проверку кода Python? Если да, то что именно?

Comment: Я использую pyCharm, и вроде бы со стилем программирования проблем нет, так как там автоматически указываются отступления от стандарта PEP8, а вот с документированием - беда. Как-то выложил свои модуль, так меня зашукали, мол, научись грамотно оформлять документацию, комментариев у тебя слишком много и вообще ты быдлокодер.

Answer (score 0):

Однозначного ответа на Ваш вопрос нет. Есть стандарты и рекомендации по оформлению кода PEP8, PEP257, [Google Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/). Этот список можно дополнить, пугуглив данную тему. А вообще советую больше читать чужой код, чтобы было что и с чем сравнивать. Посмотрите, как оформляется документация в серьезных проектах.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что в чужом коде в каждом проекте все оформлено по разному.